# How to run "hg clone" command in xterm shell from java application?

Tags: java, process, mercurial, xterm

I want my application to run xterm shell and run a command "hg clone". I can't understand why the same command works perfectly when I type it directly to xterm and doesn't work when my program uses:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

where command is:

```
"xterm -e " + "'hg --debug -v clone ssh://" + host + "/ "+ src + " " + dst + " ; read ;'"
```

xterm opens and I get:

*xterm: Can't execvp: "hg: No such file or directory*

Could you help me,please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that `exec(String)` doesn't understand quotes.

Your expression:

```
"xterm -e " + "'hg --debug -v clone ssh://" + host + "/ " + 
        src + " " + dst + " ; read ;'"
```

is going to give you a string something like this:

```
"xterm -e 'hg --debug -v clone ssh://host/src dst; read ;'"
```

That is going to be split into a command and arguments equivalent to this:

```
new String[] {"xterm", "-e", "'hg", "--debug", "-v", "clone",
 "ssh://host/src", "dst;", "read", ";'"}
```

... which is garbage.  (It tells `xterm` to run the `'hg` command!)

The problem is that the `exec(String)` uses a *niave* scheme for "parsing" the command line string.  It simply splits on multiples of one or more whitespace characters ... *treating any embedded quotes and other shell meta characters as data*.

The solution is to do the command / argument splitting yourself;  e.g.

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{
        "xterm",
        "-e",
        "'hg --debug -v clone ssh://" + host + "/ " + 
                src + " " + dst + " ; read ;'"});
```

---

> Now I get error "Cannot run program "x-term": error = 2, No such file or directory"

1. The program is "xterm", not "x-term".  (You managed to get it right before ...)
2. If that is not the problem, try using the absolute pathname the program.
3. Either way, it is a good idea to try to *understand* the error message.  In this case, the error message plainly *tells* you that it cannot *run* the program ... and it *tells* you the *name* of the program that it cannot run.